# ¿como cambiar contraseña de usuario?

Tags: php, mysqli

//Estoy realizando el cambio de contraseña de un usuario pero no me lo esta permitiendo hacer ya que me sale el mensaje del ultimo else : acceso de negado.

esta es mi tabla en base de datos:

```
Fiel  type          Null  key 
id    int(11)       No    PRI
user  varchar(15)   yes   
pw    varchar(165)  yes
```

cambiarContraseña.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database"); // incluímos los datos de conexión a la BD
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { // comprobamos que la sesión esté iniciada
        if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
            if($_POST['pw'] != $_POST['usuario_clave_conf']) {
                echo "Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }else {
                $usuario_nombre = $_SESSION['user'];
                $usuario_clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["pw"]);
                $usuario_clave = md5($usuario_clave); // encriptamos la nueva contraseña con md5
                $sql = mysqli_query("UPDATE adminfun SET pw='".$pw."' WHERE user ='".$user."'");
                if($sql) {
                    echo "Contraseña cambiada correctamente.";
                }else {
                    echo "Error: No se pudo cambiar la contraseña. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
                }
            }
        }else {
?>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            <label>Nueva contraseña:</label><br />
            <input type="password" name="pw" maxlength="15" /><br />
            <label>Confirmar:</label><br />
            <input type="password" name="usuario_clave_conf" maxlength="15" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
<?php
        }
    }else {
        echo "Acceso denegado.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, si puedes escribe el código como code o pre como te indica en el editor, porque como lo tienes ahora es muy difícil entender el código.

Comment: es que precisamente quiero aprender a realizar eso me puedes explicar?

Comment: Pulsa en editar pregunta, y pulsa en las etiquetas {} que veras en el editor, después verás que pone en el editor "introducir el código aquí", y pones tu código en esa línea para que se vea bien y sea más fácil ayudarte. Otra forma es directamente dejar 4 espacios antes de escribir para que el código se vea bien, en ambos casos verás un fondo gris en la parte del código abajo en vista previa.

Comment: No hay una clave `user` en tu variable de session, por eso entra en el `else`.

Comment: en que parte del codigo?

Comment: sigue presentado el mismo mensaje

Comment: Está entrando en el último `else`, en el cual se evalúa esto: `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {  //... }else{ echo "Acceso denegado.";  }` o sea, no estás iniciando sesión al parecer. Haz un `var_dump($_SESSION);` **después de esta línea:  `session_start();`**, para ver lo que hay en tu variable de sesión.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: array(1) { ["consulta"]=> string(0) "" } Acceso denegado.

Comment: sale esto en el script esta llegando vacio

Comment: Entonces debería ser: `if(isset($_SESSION['consulta'])) {` en vez de `user`...

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Usuarios\cambiarContaseña.php on line 10

Comment: no realiza el cambio de contraseña : array(1) { ["consulta"]=> string(0) "" } Contraseña cambiada correctamente.